# Schur's Lemma and division algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, division-algebras

Let $A$ be an abelian subgroup of the unimodular group of degree $n$ (i.e. $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$). $A$ can be regarded as a group of automorphisms of a free abelian group of rank $n$ ($\mathbb Z^n$), and so also as a group of linear transformation of $V:=\mathbb Z^n\otimes \mathbb Q$. Assume that $A$ is irreducible as group of linear transformations (i.e. $V$ is simple as $\mathbb QA$-module). Let $C$ be the centralizer of $A$ in the ring of all $n\times n$ matrices whose coefficients are rational numbers. Then $C$ is a finite dimensional algebra over the field of rational numbers.

Now

1) How we can apply the Schur's lemma to infer that $C$ is a division algebra?

2) Assume 1) is proved. Why the center of $C$ is a finite extension of the field of rational number?

Comment: What does $\otimes$ mean in $F_n\otimes \mathbb Q$?

Comment: The tensor product (over $\mathbb Z$) of $F_n$ and the rationals.

Comment: Oh, it's free *abelian* group. Okay. Denoting by $F_n$ sort of confused me. Also, why write $F_n\otimes {\mathbb Q}$ instead of just plain ${\bf Q}^n$??? Is it helpful at all? (While we're at it, why write $F_n$ instead of ${\bf Z}^n$? I believe $F_n$ is usually used to denote the free group of rank $n$...).

Comment: $F_n$ it's just a my notation at the present but maybe it will be better to change it to $\mathbb Z^n$. As concern the tensor product I write $\mathbb Z^n\otimes \mathbb Q$ to underlying the fact that the autmorphisms of $\mathbb Z^n$ can be extended in a natural way to linear transformation of the vector space $V$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you should be suspecting there is a relationship between $C$ and $End_{\Bbb Q A}(V)$.

Each $f\in End_{\Bbb Q A}(V)$ is a $\Bbb Q$ linear map such that $f(a(x))=a(f(x))$ for all $x\in V$. Thus $fa=af$ for all $a\in A$. Conversely any such $\Bbb Q$-linear $f$ commuting with the elements of $a$ is a $\Bbb Q A$-linear map. So: $C=End_{\Bbb Q A}(V)$.

Since $V$ is assumed to be $\Bbb Q A$-simple, $C=End_{\Bbb Q A}(V)$ is a division algebra. It's easy to check that the center of a division algebra is  a field.

Finally, notice that the center is a $\Bbb Q$ subalgebra of the finite dimensional $\Bbb Q$-algebra $M_n(\Bbb Q)$: it can't have any more dimensions than $M_n(\Bbb Q)$. Since it contains $\Bbb Q$, it's a field extension of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks. I was having trouble to find a relation between $C$ and $End_{\mathbb Q}(V)$; I needed to add an $A$!

Comment: @W4cc0 Glad it helped! :)